# How do I remotely administer my Svn Edge site?

Tags: svn, collabnet, subversion-edge

I am setting up [CollabNet SVN Edge](http://www.collab.net/svnedge). So far it's great but I'm wondering how I should access the admin functions from another machine. While connected to the server, I see I can access the remote console at:

> https://localhost:4434

Is the recommended approach to simply open up port 4434 on the machine's firewall and use that same address (with the host name, obviously)?

Or should I be getting to the admin area another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any confirmation that this is the right thing to do, *but* the installer *did* add an exception to the firewall to access the admin console at the address listed in the question, so I guess that's a reasonable thing to do.